# jquery validation plugin with partial view ajax loaded

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, partial-views

I'm using [Jquery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin for validate my remotely loaded partial view form modal .

```
var formDataSource = $('#frmDataSource').validate({
    rules: {
        provider: { required: true },
        stype: { required: true },
        url: { required: true },
        uname: { required: true, digits: true },
        pword: { required: true }
    },
    messages: {
        provider: { required: 'Please enter provider name' },
        stype: { required: 'Please select type' },
        url: { required: 'Please enter url' },
        uname: { required: 'Please enter user name' },
        pword: { required: 'Please enter password' }
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.insertAfter(element.parent());
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
         //submit form
    }
});
```

My Partial view

```
<div class="modal-body no-padding">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddProvider", "DataSource", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmDataSource", @class = "smart-form" }))
    {
        <fieldset>
            <div class="row">
                <section class="col col-5">
                    <label class="select">
                        <i class="icon-append fa fa-question-circle"></i>
                        @Html.DropDownList("providers", ViewBag.ProviderSelectList as List<SelectListItem>, new { name = "provider", placeholder = "Provider Name" })
                        <i></i>
                    </label>
                </section>
                <section class="col col-3 col-lg-offset-3">
                    <label class="toggle">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(d => d.IsActive, new { name = "chkbxactive" })
                        <i data-swchon-text="ON" data-swchoff-text="OFF"></i>Active
                    </label>
                </section>

            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <section class="col col-5">
                    <label class="select">
                        <select name="stype" class="input-sm" required="">
                            <option value="1">FTP</option>
                        </select> <i></i>
                    </label>
                </section>
                <section class="col col-5">
                    <label class="input">
                        <i class="icon-append fa fa-question-circle"></i>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(d => d.Address, new { name = "url", placeholder = "URI" })
                        <b class="tooltip tooltip-bottom-right"><i class="fa fa-warning txt-color-teal"></i> URI</b>
                    </label>
                </section>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <section class="col col-5">
                    <label class="input">
                        <i class="icon-append fa fa-question-circle"></i>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(d => d.UserName, new { name = "uname", placeholder = "Username" })
                        <b class="tooltip tooltip-bottom-right"><i class="fa fa-warning txt-color-teal"></i> Username</b>
                    </label>
                </section>
                <section class="col col-5">
                    <label class="input">
                        <i class="icon-append fa fa-question-circle"></i>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(d => d.Password, new { name = "pword", placeholder = "Password", type = "password" })
                        <b class="tooltip tooltip-bottom-right"> <i class="fa fa-warning txt-color-teal"></i> Password</b>
                    </label>
                </section>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <footer>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                Cancel
            </button>
            <button id="btn-frmsubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-info">
                Save
            </button>
        </footer>
    }
</div>
```

above code isn't validating and submitting then i tried this

```
$(document).on('submit', '#frmDataSource', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var validator = $("#frmDataSource").validate({
        rules: {
            provider: { required: true },
            stype: { required: true },
            url: { required: true },
            uname: { required: true, digits: true },
            pword: { required: true }
        },
        messages: {
            provider: { required: 'Please enter provider name' },
            stype: { required: 'Please select type' },
            url: { required: 'Please enter url' },
            uname: { required: 'Please enter user name' },
            pword: { required: 'Please enter password' }
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        }
    });

})
```

still form isn't submitting what was the problem with my code ?
how to submit form when it remotely loaded?

**EDIT**

as requested [Sparky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/594235/sparky)

- Simply validation is not working because validation rules not
- applying. There's no console error because it's not a error. it's not
  applying validation rules.

Regards

Comment: What does "not submitting" mean?  Is the validation working?  Do you see any console errors?  Does the page refresh but the data is not sent?  Something else?  Also, only show us the ***rendered*** HTML markup of the form, not the ASP code of the view.

Comment: You would never put the `.validate()` method inside of a `submit` handler.  The `.validate()` method is only used for ***initializing*** the plugin and goes inside the DOM ready event handler where it's called one time.  Also, if your ASP project is using the `unobtrusive-validation` plugin, then you must remove it as it will not allow you to *directly* use the jQuery Validate plugin's `.validate()` method.

Comment: Hi sparky I have came up with alternative solution. I'll post as answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue. i'll post for reference.

i have assigned validation rules before on showing modal window using `show.bs.modal` event. (not load on index page) here is the code sample.

```
$('#btn-addDataSource').on('click', function() {
    $('#register-modal').load('@Url.Action("AddProvider", "DataSource")', function() {
        $(this).one('show.bs.modal', function() {
            var validator = $("#frmDataSource").validate({
                rules: {
                    provider: { required: true },
                    providerName: { required: true },
                    stype: { required: true },
                    Address: { required: true },
                    UserName: { required: true },
                    Password: { required: true }
                },
                messages: {
                    provider: { required: 'Please enter provider name' },
                    providerName: { required: 'Please enter provider name' },
                    stype: { required: 'Please select type' },
                    Address: { required: 'Please enter url' },
                    UserName: { required: 'Please enter user name' },
                    Password: { required: 'Please enter password' }
                },
                errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                    error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                }
            });
        }).modal({
            backdrop: 'static',
            keyboard: true
        });
    });
});
```